# Slow grunt watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

i've set up a simple grunt environment on a Windows 7 Professional System. Here is the gruntfile.js I've created:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sftp-deploy');

 grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  'sftp-deploy': {
   build: {
    auth: {
     host: '',
     port: 22,
     authKey: ''
    },
   cache: 'sftpCache.json',
   src: '/css',
   dest: '/public_html/css',
   exclusions: ['/css/**/.DS_Store', '/css/**/Thumbs.db', 'dist/tmp', '/css/dev', '/css/*.map'],
   serverSep: '/',
   localSep: '/',
   concurrency: 4,
   progress: true
   }
  },
  compass: {
   dist: {
    options: {
    sassDir: '/css/dev',
    cssDir: '/css',
    environment: 'production'
    }
   },
   dev: {
    options: {
    sassDir: '/css/dev',
    cssDir: '/css'
    }
   }
  },
  watch: {
   css: {
    files: '**/*.scss',
    tasks: ['compass:dev']
   },
   ftp: {
    files: 'css/*.css',
    tasks: ['sftp-deploy']
   }
  }
 });

 grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);

}
```

If I fire up grunt everything works fine, but very slow. It takes up to 15 seconds to complete the three tasks:

[slow grunt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJZca.png)

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: task complete time depends on your PC power, but grunt works slow in old machines, use gulp. gulp is much faster then grunt

Comment: 15 seconds is not unreasonably long for those tasks. It is probably the sftp task that takes up most of the time, as it involves uploading all files in the directory over sftp.

Answer (score 0):

Originally taken from: 
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/69

> By default this watch task will spawn task runs as child processes.
>   For some systems, especially on Windows it can be really slow. Set the
>   option: nospawn: true.
>
> https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionsnospawn
>   https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#why-spawn-as-child-processes-as-a-default